# Django Exception : AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")

Tags: python, django

I found a lot of content on the AppRegistryNotReady Exception, but none of them seem defenitive. I just wanted my 2 cents of info on the topic.

My django project was working fine. I created a new app, and created the following model. No view, no urls nothing. Just a model.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class File(models.Model):
    path = models.TextField() #The path does not include MEDIA_ROOT, obviously
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    # file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_to)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=path+filename)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.PROTECT) #Protects User from being deleted when there are files left

    def clean(self):
        #Check if path has a trailing '/'
        if self.path[-1]!='/':
            self.path = self.path+"/"
        if self.filename[0]=='/':
            self.filename = self.filename[1:]

        #Get the full path
        username = self.user.__dict__[User.USERNAME_FIELD] #Need to do this the roundabout way to make sure that this works with CUSTOM USER MODELS. Else, we could have simply went for self.user.username
        self.path = "tau/"+username+"/"+self.path

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        if path[-1]=='/':
            text = "\n"+str(path)+str(filename)
        else:
            text = "\n"+str(path)+"/"+str(filename)
        return text
```

Then I tried to makemigrations on the model. And ended up with the following error.

```
(test) ~/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/stud$python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/stud/tau/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    User = get_user_model()
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 163, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 192, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/raghuram/Workspace/WebDevelopment/Django/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Just for the sake of completing the test, I changed my model to this,

```
class File(models.Model):
        file = models.FileField()
```

And that stopped the exception. So my guess is that the Exception was being raised by this.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

But I need to use that, since Im working with custom User Model. Any idea on how I can make it happen?

Comment: Have you tried `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbstractBaseUser` provides a `get_username()` method which you can use instead. It practically does the same as what you're doing: `return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)`.

```
class File(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        #Check if path has a trailing '/'
        if self.path[-1]!='/':
            self.path = self.path+"/"
        if self.filename[0]=='/':
            self.filename = self.filename[1:]

        #Get the full path
        username = self.user.get_username()
        self.path = "tau/"+username+"/"+self.path
```

The reason your original method failed is because `get_user_model()` is executed when the module is first imported, at which time the app registry is not fully initialized. If you need to use `get_user_model()` in a `models.py` file, you should call it within a function or method, not at the module level:

```
class File(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        User = get_user_model()
```

Comment: Yeah.. I ended up putting the get_user_model() inside a function.

Thanks a lot.